# State is not updated by eventhandler dispatch - React challenge

Tags: reactjs

I've tried to solve the third challange in ["Extract state logic into a reducer"](https://react.dev/learn/extracting-state-logic-into-a-reducer#challenges) unit, but my solution isn't working. More specifically, when you type something in the chatbox the state doesn't update so it keeps showing the same, like if you weren't typing.

Here is my code in Chat.js

```
export default function Chat({contact, message, dispatch}) {
  return (
    <section className="chat">
      <textarea
        value={message}
        placeholder={'Chat to ' + contact.name}
        onChange={(e) => {
          dispatch({
            type: 'edited_message',
            id: contact.id, 
            msg: e.target.value,
          });
        }}
      />
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          alert(`Sending "${message}" to ${contact.email}`);
          dispatch({
            type: 'sent_message',
            id: contact.id,
            msg: '',
          });
        }}>
        Send to {contact.email}
      </button>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Here is my in messanger reducer

```
case 'edited_message': {
      return {
        ...state,
        message: [...state.message, {id:action.id, 
                                     msg:action.msg}],
      };
    }
```

Here is my code in App.js

```
export default function Messenger() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(messengerReducer, 
                                       initialState);
  const message = state.message.find(m => 
    m.id === state.selectedId).msg;
  const contact = contacts.find((c) => 
    c.id === state.selectedId);
  return (
    <div>
      <ContactList
        contacts={contacts}
        selectedId={state.selectedId}
        dispatch={dispatch}
      />
      <Chat
        key={contact.id}
        message={message}
        contact={contact}
        dispatch={dispatch}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```